# Stripe in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, api, stripe-payments

I would like to implement Stripe on my Angular 14 project without stripe-ngx because the pop-up design isn't appropriate for me.

So, I use the "Personalized payment tunnel" and I want to catch in my component if the payment is "Succeeded" without redirect to a new URL. That is possible?

Morever, I tryed to implement the full JS checkout in my Angular component but an error is returned to me when I call the method :

```
const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elem,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: `http://localhost/example`,
      receipt_email: emailAddress,
    },
  });
```

He don't find my "clientSecret" while he's in my variable "elem".
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I add the redirect: "id_required" like this :

```
const { error } = await this.stripe.confirmPayment({
  elements,
  confirmParams: {
    receipt_email: this.emailAddress,
  },
  redirect: "if_required"
});


if (error && (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error")) {
  this.showMessage(error.message);
} else {
  this.showMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
}
```

But Stripe return me "An unexpected error occurred."

About this :

> What's the exact error message you get, and can you console.log the elem object just before calling confirmPayment()?

I'd fix this error, its good thx.